# Affable Geek has passed away

Tags: discussion

I have learned today that one of our moderators, Affable Geek, has passed away.  He was one of the best posters, if not the best poster at Politics.SE, and he was a great moderator.

He will be missed.

[Here's the thread at Christianity.SE that broke the news](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4496/lets-take-a-moment-to-remember-affable-geek)

Comment: On C.SE, we have a [chatroom for this.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21424/affable-geek-memorial) I know he was a mod here, but on Christianity he was our top user all-time, and dearly loved. Though none of us knew him personally, it's a shock and a source of grief that he's gone. If anyone from Politics wants to talk, we're open.

Comment: Sad news. Michael was an excellent moderator, and a very kind and considerate person.  He will be missed.

Comment: Oh man, that's very sad. He seems like he was a very good person.